# Websocket proxy pass to different routes

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, nginx, socket.io

Im trying to setup different socket.io servers under different locations for example:

socket.yourdomain.com/app1
socket.yourdomain.com/app2
exectra...

This subdomain is secured using a valid ssl certificate and not self signed.

nginx vhost

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/some_cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/somekey.key;


    server_name socket.yourdomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1340/;
    }
    location /app1/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1340/;
    }
    location /app2/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1341/;
    }
}
```

Server Code

```
var socket_server = require('socket.io');
var io = socket_server.listen(1340);
io.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log('connected!');
  io.emit('status', status);
});
```

If I connect to the socket.io server on the / location it works fine, however under any of the app routes there is no response (as a test I used the same socket server code on each port so I know its not that);

nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: You have specified proxy_pass with a URI (the / character after the port value). Is it intentional? Because if it isn't, this might well be the reason your configuration doesn't work as expected. The documentation states that if the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive. So in every case the request URI that is sent to a backend server is actually /, not /app1/ or /app2/.

Comment: Ive tried a lot of different version including removing the / after the port. What would be the best way to get this working with one subdomain and multiple locations ?

Comment: I used your Nginx configuration and your server code and everything works fine. Could you show your client code for both the main application and app1?